# Converting Unicode escapes in a string to their respective characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, unicode

I have the following string:

```
trouble&\u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442
```

and would like to replace the escaped characters by their actual characters, like this:

```
trouble&тест
```

How can I do so in JavaScript?

Comment: Take a look below link. It has solution how to Convert utf8 to utf16 and reverse way. https://gist.github.com/weishuaiwang/4221687

Comment: Convert and do what? How are you intending to use the string? If you do a `console.log('trouble&\u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442')` you'll see that JS is already OK with the string as it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with the `normalize` method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize

https://jsfiddle.net/fyo0y863/

You can read more about Unicode in this excellent article :) https://dmitripavlutin.com/what-every-javascript-developer-should-know-about-unicode/

**EDIT: As pointed out in two comments the string is already ok. Anyway, the link to Dmitri Pavlutin's blog is a good place to improve our comprehension of Unicode :)**

Comment: thanks a lot. I spent a lot of time for converting it and it has so simple solution

Comment: If you need IE compatibility i think you can do something similar:  
```var str = 'trouble&\u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442'; console.log([...str].join(''));```

Comment: Btw the string in OP's question is already normalized, ie: `var s = "trouble&\u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442"; console.log(s === s.normalize());` prints `true`, meaning they have the same codepoints and thus the same binary representation. The rest of the provided material is very good though.

Comment: mmm you are right...my answer doesn't make sense :)